# Unable to deploy django application on amazon linux

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to deploy Django 1.11.13 based project on Amazon Linux using virtualenv.

Here is my configuration for WSGI:

```
Alias /static /var/www/cryptoapp/static
<Directory /var/www/cryptoapp/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess cryptoapp python-home=/var/www/djangoenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages python-path=/var/www/cryptoapp
WSGIProcessGroup cryptoapp
WSGIScriptAlias /cryptoapp /var/www/cryptoapp/cryptoapp/wsgi.py process-group=cryptoapp

WSGIPassAuthorization On

<Directory /var/www/cryptoapp/cryptoapp>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If i run my project in virtualenv, it runs successfully but when i want to access from browser. It's not working and getting error like this:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encode
ImportError: No module named 'encoding'

Current thread 0x00007f23d9878840
```

Note: I have tested all the possible ways like reconfigure virtualenv and python 3 configuration.

Comment: did you use uwsgi or gunicorn?

Comment: i am using wsgi

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem on your PYTHONPATH and so when you run with WSGI mod you are using Python2 instead of python3. The module named 'encoding' is only setup on your Python3 folder but it doesn't exist on the Python 2 installation folder.

You should indicate the PYTHONPATH to your virtualenv Python3 folder.

Comment: I have create virtualenv for python3 and its points to python 3.5.5. i have checked

Comment: Yes but you have to mentionned on your VHOST the PYTHONPATH

Comment: watch my wsgi setup, i have already given PYTHONHOME & PYTHONPATH to point out Python

Comment: I also had a lots of problem with WSGI, things often went wrong. So now I am on Gunicorn&Apache and it's better to use. Hope you will find the solution.